# Study about $A=(a_{i,j})=\max(i,j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on an old French competitive exam that deals with the study of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ such that its coefficients are $\max(i,j)$.

I already made a post but the details were messy and it was better for me to rewrite it. My study is the following :

By writing $AX = \lambda X$ for $X$ an eigenvector and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue, I obtained something like

\begin{aligned}
 x_1+2x_2+ 3x_3+\dots+nx_n&=\lambda x_1 \\
 2x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\dots+nx_n&=\lambda x_2 \\
\vdots\newline
 \left(n-1\right)x_1+\left(n-1\right)x_2+\left(n-1\right)x_3+\dots+nx_n&=\lambda x_{n-1} \\
 n x_1+n x_2+n x_3+\dots+nx_n&=\lambda x_n\\
\end{aligned}

With substitutions between members of this set of equations (and knowing $0 \notin \text{Sp}\left(A\right)$), I've show that it is equivalent to solve the system :

\begin{equation}x_2 = \frac{\lambda + 1}{\lambda}x_1\end{equation} \begin{equation}\lambda x_{p+1}-\left(2 \lambda + 1\right)x_p+\lambda x_{p-1} = 0\end{equation} for $2 \leq p \leq n-1$ and \begin{equation}\left[\left(n-1\right)\lambda + n\right] x_n - n \lambda x_{n-1} = 0\end{equation}.

This new set is split into three formulae, if i'm not mistaken. This shows that $A$ has exactly $n$ different eigenvalues and the set of equations for $2 \leq p \leq n-1$ is a second order linear recursive sequence which can be solve from
$$
r^2 - \underset{=2a}{\left(2-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)}r + 1 = 0
$$
if $a = -1$, then $\lambda = -1/4$ and it is not an eigenvalue. So, I've found for $x_0=x_1$ and knowing that the roots satisfy $r_1 \cdot r_2 = 1$ that
$$
x_p = A\left(r^p+\frac{1}{r^{p-1}}\right)
$$
where $r$ is one root of the mentioned quadratic polynomial equation.

The next question of the exam (from 1991) , which I cannot answer, is :

> Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $r$ must satisfy
> $$
>  r^{2n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)r^{2n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)r+1=0
>  $$

I've no clue about it, I've tried to plug $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ onto the last set of equation but it doesn not help. Any hint ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the exam?

Comment: The determinant is integer sequence [A181983](https://oeis.org/A181983)

Comment: In [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html): `[ Matrix(n, n, lambda i,j: max(i+1,j+1)).eigenvals() for n in range(1,5) ]`

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I've been searching and I've found the result, it was not difficult ... Thank you for the time you spent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched and found the answer to my own question and I'll post it, maybe someone will be interested. The result comes from three relations :

-> First, the global expression of $x_p$ found previously :
$$
x_p = \frac{x_1}{1+r}\left(r^p+\frac{1}{r^{p-1}}\right)
$$
-> Secondly, it must be noticed that $r$ and $\lambda$ are related by :
$$
\lambda = \frac{r}{\left(r-1\right)^2}
$$

-> The last relation :
$$\left[\left(n-1\right)\lambda + n\right] x_n - n \lambda x_{n-1} = 0$$

Then we need to have
$$
\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}} = \frac{n \lambda}{\left(n-1\right)\lambda + n}=\frac{nr}{nr^2- nr +n-r}
$$
but using the global expression of $x_p$, we have
$$
\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}} = \frac{r^{2n-1} + 1}{r^{2n-2}+r}
$$
By equalizing the last two equations, we obtain

> $$
>  r^{2n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)r^{2n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)r+1=0
>  $$